# How do I lazy load a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading

So, hypothetically speaking, if I have an object, lets say it's a exception response I want to send back from a service BUT only if an exception is thrown as I have a different animal I'm sending back if everything's fine.  How do I get it from Spring... but only if I need it? In other words, how do I avoid injecting objects I don't yet need and can't be sure that I will? How do I do lazy loading using Spring?

Comment: Are you injecting beans into this exception response? Can it just be a POJO?

Comment: Just create it outside of Spring if it hits an exception flow? Or else use the `Lazy` annotation, but bare in mind the IoC container will init the object if its required by another bean. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html

Comment: It will probably be scoped Request anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. `@Lazy` on the bean definition + `ObjectFactory` or `Provider` or on the injection point
2. `@Lazy` on the bean definition + `@Lazy` on the injection point

example #2

```
@Service
@Lazy
class LazyService {

    LazyService() {
        System.out.println("service");
    }

    String bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
        return "bar";
    }
}

@RestController
class Controller {

    private final LazyService service;

    Controller(@Lazy LazyService service) {
        this.service = service;
        System.out.println("controller");
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    String foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
        return service.bar();
    }
}
```

`LazyService` is instantiated when method `Controller.foo()` is called for the first time.